# GSAP Performance & Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

GSAP claims to use HTML5 to perform outstanding animations for web use, but says clearly in the their article on [Greensock.com](http://www.greensock.com/why-gsap/) that it does not use the canvas frame work in html5. It is clear that they are using Javascript from the provided [script](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com), but it is very confusing to interpret. In what other way would they use html5 animations without the canvas? And if they do use pure HTML5 does this mean that HTML5 animations are significantly faster than CSS, jQuery, and Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not such thing as "html5 animations".

There are, mainly, CSS3 animations (with either CSS transition or CSS animations) and Javascript animations.

CSS3 animations are generally well optimised (with a few quirks) but lacks support (old IEs) and flexibility (you'll have to use JavaScript to tweak them.) They're best for hover effect (with transitions) or basic animations.

JavaScript transition used to be based on a setInterval. A timed loop, and inside this loop the styles are changed. JQuery does this, and not very well.

Recently, Window.requestAnimationFrame() was introduced to replace these setInterval animations. Support is limited (old IEs), performance is top notch (because the browser can skip frames), and it's always style updates inside.

What GSAP does is using this requestAnimationFrame() while optimizing for less repaints and adding a lot of useful features (reverse, timelines, stagger...) On basic animations, you can achieve the same performances with CSS3 or your own JS code... if you know what to do.

There are also others animations (canvas, svg... event webgl) but more specialized.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. :) There is alot of buzz on the internet on what methods are the fastest or whether it really even makes a noticeable difference. GSAP claims to be the fastest because it handles intense animation better where-ease CSS3 has shortcomings. I do not want to use GSAP and personally hate secondary javascript libraries because there is a number of them. Should I stick with the CSS3/javascript way of animating or go with the new addition in HTML5/javascript?

Comment: It depends on your project. I used to be anti-GSAP (I was doing my animations in CSS3 + native JS if needed), and then I stumbled on a very complex project (a webapp full of crazy animations) and GSAP has been... invaluable. That's a great library, but only for complicated stuff. Otherwise it's not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

In my limited experience with GSAP, and during some discussion with the developer of [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), it seems that GSAP has some very convoluted code that is quite difficult to interpret; I'm not sure if this is because they're purposefully obfuscating the code or that they do some very crazy optimizations... Maybe a bit of both. They may have also taken native code and created a Javascript implementation. In any case it makes reading the source quite difficult to do.

As far as your question about HTML5 animation, which I'm taking to mean animating objects on the DOM without Javascript, if you're using a compliant browser, you can achieve many animations via the CSS `transform` and `transition` property, the former being about DOM object transformations (moving it 10px to the left) and the latter being about how the object moves as it transforms (does it move linearly over a period of time, or use a user specified cubic bezier curve to describe its motion?). With current compliant browsers, the main difference in these properties besides vendor prefixes like `-webkit-` and  `-moz-` is small. What this means is that you can reliably get animations on DOM objects across those browsers if you take case of the prefixes. You can use these transform/transition properties to manipulate almost any DOM object property.

In terms of speed, it depends. CSS animation is generally the faster between it and Javascript, but it lacks control because it's hard/impossible to manipulate certain properties like key frames. Javascript animation is slower, but using a good library makes this difference negligible and in some cases Javascript animation can be faster. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. CSS and newer Javascript library animation is *considerably* faster than jQuery due to some reasons listed [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation).

*: Of course some browsers, like IE9 and 10, while being relatively compliant, do miss some properties and have quirks about their rendering engines.

Comment: I am trying to create a user-friendly web creation tool that allows an amateur web-designer the freedom of performing any type of tween animation with no problems at all making their website very interactive. Even thinking about the possibility for them to make a small javascript game within the browser.

Comment: As in, allowing them to see what would happen if they put properties on an object and see what happens when the property is changed?

Comment: Yeah something like that. It's only theoretical right now since I am trying to find out what I need to do performance wise before I start programming. But I was thinking with translations I could just give the user the ability to start an animation phase on the DOM element and set a time interval to determine where the element needs to be over the given time. It would be the same way with rotations, scales, fades, and transformations. The web program would be click and drag to set the objects scale and positioning.

Comment: You could create a system that creates a CSS transition or transform string and adds it to the DOM object's `style`, but that would break if you ever used a templating system like Ractive without extending the functionality of the system. It also wouldn't deal with some use cases, so I think your best bet is to use a library like Velocity or GSAP, with my choice being Velocity since it integrates with jQuery very nicely and seems to be the best performant library.